# Files missing after os.rename()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a `for` loop that works through a directory and extracts files from within each `.tar.gz` within that directory. It extracts the content from each `.tar.gz` to a temporary directory made for each `.tar.gz` and then renames them so that they can be moved to a final directory.

The temporary directory is made for each `.tar.gz` so that only the files from within each are dealt with. Once the rename is complete, the temporary directory is deleted, only to be made again for the next `.tar.gz`.

Each `.tar.gz` holds 3 files within. This is a guarantee, not an assumption.

What is happening is after renaming, upon inspection I may find myself 1-4 files short in the final directory. For example, if I started with 250 `.tar.gz` files, I should have 750 final files but I may only have 746. Since the final files are renamed such that they match the originating `.tar.gz` I can go back and manually unzip it to successfully retrieve the 3 files.

Need to discover why the `os.rename()` method is doing what it is.

The current code:

```
def unzip(in_dir):

    final_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(in_dir, "UNZIPPED\\"))
    temp_dir = os.path.join(in_dir, "TEMP\\")

    os.mkdir(final_dir)

    files = [f for f in os.listdir(in_dir) if f.endswith('.tar.gz')]

    for item in files:
        os.mkdir(temp_dir)
        org_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(in_dir, item))
        tar = tarfile.open(org_path, 'r:gz')
        tar.extractall(path=temp_dir)
        tar.close()
        for member in os.listdir(temp_dir):
            new_path= os.path.abspath(os.path.join(temp_dir, member))
            os.rename(new_path, 
                      os.path.join(final_dir,
                                   os.path.basename(org_path)[:-7]+new_path[-4:]))
        os.rmdir(temp_dir)
```

If I am misusing `os.path.abspath` and/or `os.path.join` please point it out. I would think that by passing `in_dir` as something such as `C:\MyPath` then the use of `os.path.join(in_dir, "UNZIPPED\\")` would yield `C:\MyPath\UNZIPPED\` and I wouldn't need to use `os.path.abspath` before it.

Comment: `oslistdir`: typo?

Comment: you could count the inner loop to see if you're iterating 750 times. Also, check if target files doesn't already exist. `os.rename` wouldn't overwrite the file but maybe it's just implementation defined. Also check that you don't have subdirs in your tgz archives. Because you're just scanning the root of the extracted directory, not the subdirs.

Comment: Consider extracting the files with `tarfile.extractfile()`, this will give you a file like object that you can then write to the desired directory with the desired name, therefore avoiding all renames and moves on the extracted files

Comment: `tar = tarfile.open(item, 'r:gz')` shouldn't that be `tar = tarfile.open(org_path, 'r:gz')`? Even though you need `os.path.join` to get to files enumerated by `os.listdir`, there is no need to do `abspath` on them. Harmless, but unneeded.

Comment: Also check the file names, `os.rename()` will not overwrite files in windows, but will raise OSError exception, make sure you are not catching it elsewhere.

Comment: @Dalvenjia Each `.tar.gz` file has a unique name (as such by date file was generated, and we only generate 1 per day YYYY-MM-DD format). It is odd that with a manual extraction, all files are there, and when I run the code with some manual debugging in the `for member...` loop with a `print member` it always prints each of the 3 files. It just doesn't always seem to rename and move.